# Can Galaxybase modify the service port, and how?

Tags: graph-databases

Galaxybase's default service port overlaps with other ports, how to modify it?

I wonder if there is any way I can change the port mapping, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the installation and deployment, you can modify the graph service port.
When executing the build command, you can set port mapping using the -p parameter in the format "-p default port：port mapping".
If you need to modify multiple ports, please set multiple -p parameters.